# The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget)' Error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, provider, flutter-change-notifier

This is a code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/ui/pages/notes_home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/ui/pages/splash.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/ui/pages/user_info.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/ui/pages/auth/login.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/model/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
      child: Consumer
        // ignore: missing_return
        (builder: (context, UserRepository user, _) {
          // ignore: missing_return
          switch (user.status){
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return Splash();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return LoginPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return NotesHomePage();
          }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

The line "builder: (_) => UserRepository.instance()," in above code shows a error

The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget)'

and whenever I run the program it shows that

Could not find the correct Providerabove this LoginPage Widget

UserRepository code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

enum Status { Uninitialized, Authenticated, Authenticating, Unauthenticated }

class UserRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  FirebaseUser _user;
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;

  UserRepository.instance()
      : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance,
        _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn() {
      _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_onAuthStateChanged);
  }

  Status get status => _status;
  FirebaseUser get user => _user;

  Future<bool> signIn(String email, String password) async{
    try {
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> signUp(String email, String password) async{
    try {
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> signInWithGoogle() async{
    try{
      _status =Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      return true;
    }catch(e) {
      print(e);
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    _auth.signOut();
    _googleSignIn.signOut();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }

  Future<void> _onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async{
    if(firebaseUser == null) {
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    }else{
      _user = firebaseUser;
      _status = Status.Authenticated;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Please help

Here is a login page code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/model/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool signInForm;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    signInForm = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async{
        if(!signInForm) {
          setState(() {
            signInForm = true;
          });
          return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: kToolbarHeight),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  width: 60.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Colors.red,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text('Google'),
                  onPressed: () async{
                    if(!await user.signInWithGoogle())
                      showmessage();
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                AnimatedSwitcher(
                  child: signInForm ? LoginForm() : SignupForm(),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                OutlineButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child: signInForm ? Text("Sign Up", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),) : Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      signInForm = !signInForm;
                    });
                  },
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                  highlightColor: Colors.white,
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void showmessage(){
    _key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Somethimg is wrong"),
    ));
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function showError;

  const LoginForm({Key key, this.showError}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final FocusNode passwordField = FocusNode();
  TextEditingController _email;
  TextEditingController _password;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Login", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _email,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Email"
              ),
              onEditingComplete: (){
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordField);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _password,
              focusNode: passwordField,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Password"
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.red,
              child: Text("Login"),
              onPressed: () async{
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                  if(!await user.signIn(
                    _email.text, _password.text))
                    widget.showError();
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SignupForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupFormState createState() => _SignupFormState();
}

class _SignupFormState extends State<SignupForm> {
  final FocusNode passwordField = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode confirmPasswordField = FocusNode();
  TextEditingController _email;
  TextEditingController _password;
  TextEditingController _confirmpassword;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    _confirmpassword = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Sign Up", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _email,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Email"
              ),
              onEditingComplete: (){
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordField);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
            TextFormField(
              obscureText: true,
              controller: _password,
              focusNode: passwordField,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Password"
              ),
              onEditingComplete: ()=> FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(confirmPasswordField),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
            TextFormField(
              obscureText: true,
              controller: _confirmpassword,
              focusNode: confirmPasswordField,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Confirm Password"
              ),
              onEditingComplete: (){
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordField);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.red,
              child: Text("Create Account"),
              onPressed: () async{
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                  if(_confirmpassword.text == _password.text)
                    if(!await user.signUp(
                      _email.text, _password.text))
                      print("Failed to Signup");
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

In your code, simply change

```
builder: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
```

to

```
create: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
```

and everything will work just fine!

Comment: Thanks.  It made my day.  Spent a day to figure out the error messages, but couldn't on my own.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

**I am very new to flutter and I had same issue, then I solved with this solution..**

> **I replaced `builder` with `create` as shown in image.**

[image]

Comment: For me, adding "ctx" inside parentheses solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

for provider 3.2 and up you should use create instead of builder

Answer (score 3):

from the version 5.0.0 of provider package, we should use '**create**' instead of '**builder**' in **ChangeNotifierProvider** .

Answer (score 1):

Use **create**: instead builder: in ChangeNotifiereProvider()

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserRepository>(
      create: (context) => UserRepository.instance(),
      child: Consumer
        // ignore: missing_return
        (builder: (context, UserRepository user, child) {
          // ignore: missing_return
          switch (user.status){
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return Splash();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return LoginPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return NotesHomePage();
          }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Error in android studio is gone, installation is also completed by using above your code but in Mobile it was not working. After launching on screen it showing error: Could not find the Correct Provider<UserRepository> above this LoginPage widget.

Comment: what is your log?

Comment: sorry I didn't get your question....what do you mean by log ?

Comment: why you used *** WillPopScope*** ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late but I would like to specify that we can use both `create`, `build` and they work too! Maybe I'm missing something but if docs still says that `builder` can be used I think we should.

By the way this is how you should use it to fix the error :

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
      builder : (newContext,child){ //You will use this context here
          return Consumer....
      }
      child : CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Be careful when using `context`s, is easy to pass the wrong one. In this case you need to use `newContext` below.
I used `CircularProgressIndicator` as `child` but you can use whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

you can put "BuildContext context, Widget? child"
inside the round brackets(Parameter) of builder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).